# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘prophet’

Tags: r, facebook-prophet

I have installed Rtools(rtools35.exe) and also installed `rstan` before installing `prophet` but it gives me error everytime like this

```
> library(prophet)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘prophet’:  .onLoad failed
>   in loadNamespace() for 'prophet', details:   call:
>   system2(file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "bin", "R"), args = "CMD SHLIB
>   --dry-run",    error: 'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-35~1.2\bin\R.exe CMD SHLIB --dry-run'

My Rtools is installed in C:\Rtools whereas my R3.5.2 version is installed in C:\Program Files\R\R3.5.2

Does it have to be with the path of installation?

Answer (score 0):

**Two things to do:**

1. Install Rtools for windows 
   https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/
2. As described here:
   https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/569
   Try it after changing ~/.R/Makevars to
   CXX14 = g++ -std=c++1y

and then install prophet package